# DOS 'copy' Command from Java

Tags: java, copy, dos

I'd like to concatenate several txt files in a single directory together to form a new txt file from within a java program using the DOS command "copy *.txt NEW.txt".

How can I navigate DOS to my directory and execute the command?  I am at a loss.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why bother? Why not just copy the file in Java?

Comment: You are not really using DOS, are you? I don't think there is a JVM for DOS actually.

Comment: As bad of an idea it is to use `Runtime.exec`, it's still a legitimate question. It's worthy of not being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c copy *.txt NEW.txt", 
    null, new File("<yourDirectory>"));
```

Even thought I wouldn't suggest to do that. First, it is tricky to get right. Then, it is platform specific (only work on Windows). Instead, I would use `java.io.FileInputStream` / `java.io.FileOutputStream`

Comment: I think you have to execute cmd.exe and pass the copy string as a parameter.  As you suggested, it's much easier to do the work in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Calling DOS commands isn't a good idea. Your application will become greatly dependent on the environment and it will be much harder to properly detect and recover from IO errors. I suggest you to use [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/io/). You can easily achieve what you need by repeatedly calling one of its `copy` methods.

If you just need to read several files concatenated into a single stream, you could also use [SequenceInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Process` and set its working directory before exec-ing it.